# Slight confusion about PMOS

Tags: digital-logic, pmos

So ive really only learned about the opration of the NMOS. In woudlnt to check my understanding of the PMOS, i believe thy are very similiar.

I want to know, exactly how are the voltage applied?

I would apply a voltage between Gate B to G which is the back plate of the N subtrate.
This then accumulates positive charges onto the G plate and forming the channel field with holes.
I would then apply a voltage between S and B, this then accumulates holes at the S gate.
I would then apply a voltage between S and D in order to move the holes from S to D or the electron from D to S.

It seems like the purpose of the gate voltage is to remove the depletion region around the P-type materials so that a channel can be formed where electrons may pass. It also seems like the electrons are supplied by the n well n type material for the current. Are these observations correct?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Note that with the voltages you have drawn, the Vgs of this PMOS is **zero** (Vsourece = 5 V, Vgate = 5 V) meaning that this PMOS is now switched **off**.

Comment: @bimpelrekkie Only if it's an enhancement mode device.

Comment: This is not my drawing but, if you removed all the pen drawings. How would you turn on this PMOS transistor?

Answer (score 2):

Really, the only functional difference between P- and N-channel MOSFETs is that a P channel device is turned on with a negative Vgs and the body diode's cathode is on the source, and an N channel device is turned on with a positive Vgs and the body diode's cathode is on the drain.

Everything you know about an N-channel FET also applies to a P-channel one, if you swap the signs of all the voltages and currents.

---

An aside: there is also the additional difference that, for common semiconductor materials like silicon and SiC, P-channel devices perform worse in general--lower transconductance, higher Rdson (for the same die area), and so on. This is related to the material properties, mostly (I think?) the fact that hole mobility is so much lower than electron mobility in these semiconductors (and indeed in most semiconductors). This isn't important for a basic understanding of the devices, but if you're ever wondering why N-channel devices are so much more common, well, that's why. Or at least part of why.

---

Answering a question in the comments:

> This is not my drawing but, if you removed all the pen drawings. How would you turn on this PMOS transistor?

Apply a negative voltage to the gate with respect to body. How negative depends on the individual device, but 10 volts should be adequate to turn on most FETs. Do check your individual device, though; you want a voltage several volts above \$V_{GS,th}\$. If the datasheet specifies \$R_{DS,on}\$ at a particular gate voltage, use that voltage or higher to get the specified on resistance.

This is assuming it's an enhancement-mode device, which most are. (I've never even seen a depletion-mode p-channel MOSFET, though pJFETs obviously exist.) If it's a depletion-mode device, it's on with zero volts between body and gate, and bringing gate positive with respect to body will turn it off.

Note that neither source nor drain can be allowed to be more positive than body, without forward biasing the body diode.

Comment: This is not my drawing but, if you removed all the pen drawings. How would you turn on this PMOS transistor?

Comment: @Malemna See the edited answer.